# Anomalous scanf behaviour in C

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I am trying to run the following code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void main(){
    int firstNum = 5;
    int16_t secondNum;
    
    printf("Please enter the first number: ");
    scanf("%d", &firstNum);
    printf("Please enter the second number: ");
    scanf("%d", &secondNum);
    
    printf("%d %d\n", firstNum, secondNum);
}
```

And the output I am getting is as follows:

```
Please enter the first number: 13
Please enter the second number: 4
0 4

--------------------------------
Process exited after 1.877 seconds with return value 4
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Why is that so?

My IDE is Dev-C++. Compiler is TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit Release. Program name is TestBit.c (if that is relevant?).

Note: When I change the line `int16_t secondNum;` to `int secondNum;`, the program works as intended.

Comment: was it not possible to copy and paste the output?   Posting images of text is not the kindest thing you can do for people trying to help you.

Comment: I am sorry, I thought only copying and pasting the code was the norm. I will edit it right away.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for the harsh language.   You have two answers below which both point to the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper specifier for `int16_t secondNum` is from `<inttypes.h>`

```
// scanf("%d", &secondNum);
scanf("%" SCNd16, &secondNum);
```

Better code would check the return value.

```
if (scanf("%" SCNd16, &secondNum) == 1) {
  Success();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An int16_t is not the same thing as an int; so passing a pointer to one via scanf and pretending it is an int pointer can yield unexpected behaviour; thus your question.

Replace int16_t with int and your program works.   For followup read the C Programming Language specification of types and what they mean.

Comment: I realise the mistake there. I actually intend to use ```int16_t``` for this particular program. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to: `scanf("%hd", &secondNum);`

`%d` is a 4-byte data specifier, `int16_t` is actually only 2 bytes.

More references: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=vs-2019

Comment: `%d` in `scanf` family matches a signed integer, which doesn't have to be 4-byte-width,  and corresponding argument must be a pointer to signed integer. The appropriate specifier for `int16_t` is `"%"SCNd16` in `scanf` family.

Comment: `"%hd"` best used with `signed short`.  `int16_t` is often the same as `signed short`, but may differ.  So when it differs (rare), `scanf("%hd", &secondNum)` is UB.